# unity android output is about 120mb even with just an empty scene

Tags: unity, android

there is a lot of content in my project but as a test I just chose a empty scene with one sprite to build but the apk output size is about 120mb.

I think there is an options or setting or platform support that makes it much big but I don't know what it is.

thank you for helping

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html)?

Comment: @Draco18s yes my friend and I know the problem is unity only uses assets that are in scenes to build. when there is just one empty scene. so it means it should be minimum size for android about 21mb not 120mb

Comment: Some things are compiled in also, if you have any dll plugins or any folder named Resources, those will automatically be included, even though the scene itself is emtpty.

Comment: @Draco18s thank you, the package I used had a big res file. you can write an answer ill accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with an empty scene, anything inside any folder named `Resources` that is anywhere within the Assets directory will be included, regardless of whether or not it is in the scene or not.

This is due to it being having to be available via [`Resources.Load()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html).